# how can i remove chars between indexes in a javascript string

Tags: javascript

i have the following:

```
var S="hi how are you";
var bindex = 2;
var eindex = 6;
```

how can i remove all the chars from S that reside between bindex and eindex?
therefore S will be "hi are you"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First find the substring of the string to replace, then replace the first occurrence of that string with the empty string.

```
S = S.replace(S.substring(bindex, eindex), "");
```

Another way is to convert the string to an array, `splice` out the unwanted part and convert to string again.

```
var result = S.split('');
result.splice(bindex, eindex - bindex);
S = result.join('');
```

Comment: The first method could replace more things than you expect.

Comment: Going further, the second method will do weird stuff if unicode is present in the string. (as you're splitting using ```''```)

Comment: .replace() only replaces the first occurrence of the given string. If anything, this method would remove something unnecessary

Answer (score 58):

Take the text before bindex and concatenate with text after eindex, like:

```
var S="hi how are you"; 
var bindex = 2; var eindex = 6; 
S = S.substr(0, bindex) + S.substr(eindex);
```

S is now "hi are you"

Comment: This seems like the safest approach. Should be the accepted answer

Comment: I like this one, it avoids friendly fire.

Comment: I agree too that this answer should be the accepted answer.

Comment: substr is being deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Comment: The new alternative is just `substring` instead.

Answer (score 13):

try

```
S = S.substring(0, bindex)+S.substring(eindex);
```

Answer (score 9):

With [`String.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
S = S.slice(0, bindex) + S.slice(eindex);
```

Comment: This seems like it would be more efficient if you already knew the indexes anyway.

Answer (score 3):

A solution that doesn't require creating any intermediate arrays or strings is to use `.replace` to *capture* the first characters in a group, match the characters you want to remove, and replace with the first captured group:

```js
// keep first 3 characters, remove next 4 characters
const s = "hi how are you";
console.log(
  s.replace(/(.{3}).{4}/, '$1')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

S.split(S.substring(bindex, eindex)).join(" ");

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. get the substring from bindex and eindex
2. remove spaces from that string
3. rebuild the string

   var new_s = S.slice(1, bindex) + S.slice(bindex, eindex).replace(/\s/g, '') + S.slice(eindex)

Comment: Sorry. I misread your question, reading 'remove all spaces' instead of 'remove all the chars'

Answer (score 1):

### DON'T USE SLICE; TRY SPLICE

While `slice` is good and all, it was designed like `substring`, it was designed to get stuff, not remove stuff.

**Caveat**: splice was written for Arrays.

**Good news**: strings are easily turned into Arrays.

```
String.prototype.splice = function(start, deleteCount) {
  const newStringArray = this.split('')
  newStringArray.splice(start, deleteCount)
  return newStringArray.join('')
}

'Hello World'.splice(2, 5)
// Output -> "Heorld"
```

Comment: This doesn't really explain why you shouldn't use slice - it was designed to get parts of a string, and that's what it's doing in the above examples (even if the end result is to put the strings back together).   The split and join operations will make this function WAY slower.

Answer (score 1):

The following function returns the complementary result of slice function:

```
 String.prototype.remainderOfSlice = function(begin, end) {

    begin = begin || 0
    end = (end === undefined) ? this.length : end 

    if (this.slice(begin, end) === '') return this + ''
    return this.slice(0, begin) + this.slice(end) 
 }
```

examples:

```
 "hi how are you".slice(2, 6) // " how"
 "hi how are you".remainderOfSlice(2, 6) // "hi are you"

 "hi how are you".slice(-2, 6) // ""
 "hi how are you".remainderOfSlice(-2, 6) // "hi how are you"
```

Answer (score 0):

Want to delete multiple ranges in a string at once? It can be tricky because indexes will change as you cut out pieces of a string, but here's something quick that might work depending on your requirements:

```js
function deleteRangesInString(ranges, string, deleteChar = "▮") {
    ranges.forEach(r => {
        string = string.substring(0, r[0]) + deleteChar.repeat((r[1]-r[0])+1) + string.substring(r[1]+1);
    })
    return string.replace(new RegExp(deleteChar, 'g'), '');
}

var s = 'hi how are you, look at me now, look at me now';

console.log(
deleteRangesInString([[2,9],[14,29]], s)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only the beginning index `bindex` and length of the string you want to remove while the end index is indeterminate.

Typical use case for this is in cryptography, where you want to remove *salt* from a decrypted string (that was inserted at a known index before encryption) without exposing the value of the salt; you can expose the salt length rather than the salt value.

```js
function removeSalt(str, bindex, saltlen) {
    
    let front = str.slice(0, bindex)
    return front + str.slice(front.length + saltlen)
}

var s = "how was45r7% your day?" // can be result from a decryption function
console.log (removeSalt(s, 7, 5))
```