# How to remove [ and ] and any content in between (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How to remove '[' and ']' and the content in between if the content only contains a number?

Starting string:

```
let cityInfo = "Munich (/ˈmjuːnɪk/ MEW-nik; German: München [ˈmʏnçn̩] (listen);[3] Austro-Bavarian: Minga [ˈmɪŋ(ː)ɐ]; Latin: Monachium) is the capital and most populous city of Bavaria. With a population of around 1.5 million,[4] it is the third-largest city in Germany."
```

Some of the information between the '[ ]' I need to keep. Examples: [ˈmʏnçn̩] and [mɪŋ(ː)ɐ]
Some of it I need to remove. Examples: [3] and [4]

How would I loop through the string, removing the brackets containing numbers while leaving the ones that do not?

Desired output:
"Munich (/ˈmjuːnɪk/ MEW-nik; German: München [ˈmʏnçn̩] (listen); Austro-Bavarian: Minga [ˈmɪŋ(ː)ɐ]; Latin: Monachium) is the capital and most populous city of Bavaria. With a population of around 1.5 million, it is the third-largest city in Germany."

I've looked at several references online but all the ones I found did not seem to provide solutions for what I am trying to do. Examples of what is not going to work:
[how can i remove chars between indexes in a javascript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217557/how-can-i-remove-chars-between-indexes-in-a-javascript-string) --- 
[Replacing any content inbetween second and third underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813671/replacing-any-content-inbetween-second-and-third-underscore) --- 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split --- 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-split-and-manipulate-strings-in-javascript --- 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-remove-a-character-from-string-in-javascript/

Comment: the numbers is random ?

Comment: yes - I will not know what the numbers are beforehand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with the regular expression `/\[\d+\]/g` to match all sequences of digits within square brackets which you can then replace with an empty string (`''`):

```js
const cityInfo = "Munich (/ˈmjuːnɪk/ MEW-nik; German: München [ˈmʏnçn̩] (listen);[3] Austro-Bavarian: Minga [ˈmɪŋ(ː)ɐ]; Latin: Monachium) is the capital and most populous city of Bavaria. With a population of around 1.5 million,[4] it is the third-largest city in Germany.";

const res = cityInfo.replace(/\[\d+\]/g, '');
console.log(res);
```